# Can't update phpunit to v7

Tags: php, phpunit

I use macOs Mojave, MAMP (php 7.1.2) and lately I tried phpUnit, currently running v6.1.1.

I think I need to update phpUnit to v7, since I'm using php7.1.2.

I installed phpUnit via composer. Here some details about the current installation:

phpunit --version
PHPUnit 6.1.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

which phpunit
/usr/local/bin/phpunit

When I try to update, nothing happens:

composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^7

./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

--version
PHPUnit 6.1.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Still Version 6.1.1

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards
Beat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are running `which phpunit /usr/local/bin/phpunit` is seems you have PHPUnit installed globally at `/usr/local/bin/phpunit`.

Do you have version 7 when running `vendor/bin/phpunit --version`?

To use the local version you would need to run `vendor/bin/phpunit` instead of just `phpunit`.

To update PHPUnit globally, see the instructions here: https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/installation.html

Comment: with vendor/bin/phpunit --version I get PHPUnit 7.4.3! Nice :D Still I get an error, when I run my testcase: Error: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found. I thought this error is connected to the version of phpunit... But now I think its not ;) Do you have an idea, why I get this error? i think I need the php_intl.dll extensions, I tried to load it in phpunit.xml, but its still not working...

Comment: That's probably a different issue - sounds like namespacing (your namespaces should match up with your file paths, and be configured in `composer.json`). See here for an example: https://github.com/elliotjreed/php-package-boilerplate/

Comment: `NumberFormatter` is a PHP built-in class provided by the `intl` extension. Does your code use that? Do you have the extension installed?